# Junit test; Is it possible to configure a Bean's default property, before application context starts up?

Tags: java, spring, junit, applicationcontext, springjunit4classrunner

I have a Bean with a property "DBServer"; It has a default of "location1";

During application startup,
Depending on the value of "DBServer", different classes are instantiated.

I have 200 tests where this default setting is fine.

However, As of now,I would like to test the alternative.

Question:

Is there a way to from within a junit test case to reset the default before the application context starts ?

Comment: You should consider using Spring Profiles. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: This is exactly the use case for profiles

Comment: I tried using @profiles("useProfile1");

Comment: @Resource
    public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext m_annotationConfigApplicationContext;

    .................... 

   
   m_annotationConfigApplicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("useProfile1");
   m_annotationConfigApplicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("useProfile1Supplementary");
   m_annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
   m_annotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh();
   ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) m_annotationConfigApplicationContext).close();

Comment: But ... when i run it ............it goes looping when i do a refresh.

Comment: Just to clarify when i set the active profile and refresh and close.

Comment: It returns back to this code because I am refreshing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junit won't start application context unless you write setUp method under *@before* annotation. In that case you can initialize your bean with any values.

Comment: Ok, Thank you; From here, how can i set a particular class property (for example).............

Comment: @Configuration
public class configSetup {

    @Property(name="db.server", settable = Settable.OPTIONAL, defaultValue = "",
            description = "Host address.")
    public String dbServer = "";                     ......................................